# How to know if a particular class is reachable or not by JVM?

Tags: java

is there any way to know a particular is reachable by JVM or not, before it throws a `ClassNotFoundException` so that we can skip that class access and can use a substitute class at runtime.

Comment: Can you not just catch `ClassNotFoundException`?  But I'm thinking that you have some deeper architectural problems if you're doing this.  Look into Google Guice ( http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/ ) or Spring IoC ( http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Java/The-Spring-Framework-Understanding-IoC/ )...you'll probably find them very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one has mentioned this because for the described problem, catching ClassCastException really is the best way... however...

If all you want to do is check for existence of a .class file on the classpath then attempting to grab the class as a resource might work.

```
URL u = getClass().getResource( "/java/util/List.class" );
```

ClassLoaders that, for whatever reason, don't load their classes from reachable resources will mean the class won't be found but most of the standard class loaders will let this work.  I mention it because when it works, you have the added ability of being able to see exactly where the .class file is on disk.

Comment: Also note that this only checks for the existence of the class file. It can be present and still be un-loadable (for example when classes required by that class are not found).

Answer (score 3):

Can you show some relevant code?  Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, I'd say:

1. You should be able to make sure all classes you reference are on your classpath ahead of time.
2. If you have to, you could just catch the ClassNotFound exception where you expect it might occur and then try again with a different type.

Comment: i dont have a sample code.. but i have a scenario where i have db2 as well oracle DB to access where if i dont find db2driver class i ll use oracle or vice-versaw. hope i am clear

Comment: Sure, but then, where are these drivers coming from?  Do you have them?  Can you put them on the classpath?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should implement an solution in the exception handler for ClassNotFoundException exception.

As you want to detect if the class is reachable at runtime, there is no way to find it out before execute the program.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to ask the classloader or call Class.forName() without an receiving an exception, but it doesn't harm if this occurs only during init. 
The only possibillity would be to check the classpath for the db-jar's in the filesystem.
But that would be too much work for little (or no) benefit.